# URL encoded + (plus) evaluates to space

Tags: url, encoding, urlencode

I am trying to pass the following string as a GET parameter to a PHP script:

```
<script src="http://mypage.net/test.php?cb=
var url = 'test'+document.body.outerHTML;
//"></script>
```

URL encoded, this string becomes:

```
%3Cscript%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmypage.net%2Ftest.php%3Fcb%3D%0Avar%20url%20%3D%20%27test%27%2Bdocument.body%3B%0A%2F%2F%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A
```

Chrome and Firefox both evaluate the the encoded string after passing it a get parameter to

```
var url = 'test' document.body;
```

replacing the `%2B` with a space, hence making to code syntactically false.
`%252B` works though, which is decoded to `%2B` and evaluates to `+`

Comment: What value are you trying to get out of `document.body`? `document.body` is a DOM element and not necessarily a string, which is probably why it's not returning correctly when trying to concatenate it with `test`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the `outerHTML`. It's definetely a string.
Problem really is the `%2B` vs `%2B2B`

Comment: Are you able to post the full `.html` file so I can fully reproduce the problem?